# can I use Selenium IDE 1.0.10 with FF4.0 yet?

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-ide, firefox4

I've managed to install Selenium IDE 1.0.10 into FF4. Selenium is showing in the Add Ons Manager and I've restarted the browser. However, I don't see any way to launch the IDE. Is there something I'm missing that lets me **launch the IDE**? Not having the Selenium IDE kinda kills the usefulness of FF4 for me, so I'd really like to figure out how to launch it.

I've asked this question on the google group but got no response. The question is off the first page now so I suspect I won't get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part: **Press Alt to show the Tools menu.** After that it's the same as it used to be.

If installed and enabled then Selenium IDE should be present in the Tools menu, however Selenium IDE 1.0.11 has not yet been released and no officially released version of Selenium IDE supports Firefox 4 yet.

Comment: Point 1) At http://seleniumhq.org/download/ it says: Download version 1.0.10 under the IDE section.  My OP said 1.0.11, which was a mistake, should've said 1.0.10. Corrected it.

Comment: Point 2) If there's a Tools menu in FF4 I don't see it.

Comment: Point 3) If it isn't supported in FF4, how did I manage to install it with the xpi that I got from their site? Those xpis have, iirc, a version flag in them.

Comment: You can still install add-ons if they have been marked as compatible, or if you have the add-on compatibility reporter add-on installed.

Comment: @Dave maybe that's installed by default? I know I didn't install it. I'm wondering why they would have made their xpi FF4 compatible if it clearly doesn't work in FF4.

Comment: I found the answer, but I didn't want to answer and not give you credit for trying. So I edited your answer. The Tools menu is hidden until you press Alt.

Answer (score 4):

This should be regarded as a hack, but is possible to use Selenium 1.0.10 with Firefox 4 by installing the Add-on Compatibility Reporter extension (it allows you to install and run incompatible versions of your extensions).

The Add-on Compatibility Reporter extension can be found here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/

Comment: so nice, thanks - I've searched simple way to use Selenium in firefox4 and your post very helped me - it's work correctly